# Windows 10 Resisting Logon Configuration

Tags: windows, group-policy, login

In a newly-updated Windows 10 Professional client, Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options is configured to enable both

- Don't display last signed-in
- Don't display username at sign-in

Nevertheless, the system fails on both counts, notwithstanding toggling the policy and multiple reboots.  Specifically, the system does both.

How does one get Windows 10 to function as configured?

Comment: Can you check if you see the policy in `gpresult /h` report?

Comment: The command produced an impenetrable load of html code that I have no patience to parse through myself.

This said, the problem no longer exists.  The solution is simply to reboot six or eight times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply to reboot six or eight times.

Just keep rebooting until Windows acknowledges its own configuration and comes to heel.

Or, reinstall.  Your time is meaningless.